# Can't find file location to change template variables for {{ Title }}

Tags: html, css, node.js, github, web-applications

Trying to edit template variables for this node-prelaunch repo:

https://github.com/mailgun/node-prelaunch

I know this is an easy question for most people, but I can't seem to find the file location to edit {{ Title }} variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On what page?

The `{{ title }}` for the index page is declared here: https://github.com/mailgun/node-prelaunch/blob/master/server/routes/index.js#L27

Comment: thanks for the input, the index page {{ Title }} variable is what I was trying to edit. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're very welcome!